# Process Javascript in inactive tab on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, tabs

I have this solution that takes the user through a series of questions. At the end the user can click a button that opens a new window with a form to enter contact info. The population of this popup window is done through JavaScript from the calling window.

The process (in JS) is this:

1. Open popup window with loading gif
2. Store additional information remotely through ajax
3. Populate popup window with contact form

This all works fine in desktop browsers but not on iPads (using Safari where all windows are displayed as tabs). I have a suspicion that the JavaScript in the parent tab is halted when the "popup" tab gets displayed. To support this theory I can actually get the popup tab populated if I switch back to the parent tab immediately after the popup tab is displayed.

Can anyone confirm this? And of course if there's a solution I would very much like to hear about it.

Needless to say it works like a charm on my Android tablet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using window focus and blur to activate some javascript when the focus is back on your tab.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479936/1712686

Comment: To understand you correct: From my popup window/tab I should give focus back to my parent window/tab?

Comment: I didn't understand your question correctly. See this answer which provides more information to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11827258/1712686